# Find specific word in array in order

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
ary = [
  'ahorseride', 'amparkeetjump', 'acatlive', 'adogwish', 'bmparkeetjump',
  'bcatlive', 'bdogwish', 'bhorseride', 'brabuffallo', 'chorseride7679',
  'ceelionking5454', 'crabuffallokjkj4', 'dgiraffeoiu9-0', 'chorseride767',
  'ccatlive', 'dcatlive', 'ddogwish', 'emparkeetjump', 'emouse', 'eeelionking',
  'erabuffallo', 'ffhorseride7679', 'fgeelionking5454', 'fhcrabuffallokjkj4a',
  'fkcgiraffeoiu9087*s',
]    
big_animal = ['horse', 'lion', 'buffallo', 'giraffe']
```

For each element in `big_animal`, I would like to find which elements of `ary` include that as a substring, and present them in a specific order. I would like to achieve this result:

```
horse in the chorseride7679
lion in the ceelionking5454
buffallo in the crabuffallokjkj4
giraffe in the dgiraffeoiu9-0
```

and/or

```
horse in the ffhorseride7679
lion in the fgeelionking5454
buffallo in the fhcrabuffallokjkj4a
giraffe in the fkcgiraffeoiu9087*s
```

How do I do this? My attempt is:

```
horse = big_animal[0]
ary.each do |e|
  puts "#{horse} in the house of #{e}" if e.include?(horse)
end
```

whose result is:

```
horse in the house of ahorseride
horse in the house of bhorseride
horse in the house of chorseride7679
horse in the house of chorseride767
horse in the house of ffhorseride7679
```

Comment: May lion also be in the house of eeelionking?

Comment: Unfortunately not, lion only has to be between the founded array of horse, buffallo and giraffe. row before eelionking is emouse (and it doesn't contain horse word). But it does possible lion in the house of fgeelionking5454

Comment: what is the criteria for picking the various animals out of the array? say dgiraffeoiu9-0 vs fkcgiraffeoiu9087 for exmaple.  It is not at all clear.

Comment: What is the specific order in which you want to present the result? It is not clear at all.

Comment: @npn The animal has to be animals in variable big_animal order. It first order is 
`#horse in the chorseride7679
#lion in the ceelionking5454
#buffallo in the crabuffallokjkj4
#giraffe in the dgiraffeoiu9-0`

@sawa sorry about that. I'll edit the question

Comment: it is still not at all clear what defines the order other than listing the 4 items, that's why I guessed you wanted the ones ending in digits,  please clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have to admit that this is the very first time I'm using Ruby which is why my code might be a bit messy.

On a second note, I've seen the answer from nPn getting the output you want to have with a regex. However, this is not completely solving your problem because his solution will only retrieve values containing the big_animal and **ending with a digit**. This solution does not care about the right order of the houses.

As far as I've understood your problem, you want all the *houses* that contain the *big_animal* but only if they are in the same order. This is why I've come up with this piece of code:

```
ary = ['ahorseride', 'amparkeetjump', 'acatlive', 'adogwish', 'bmparkeetjump', 'bcatlive', 'bdogwish', 'bhorseride', 'brabuffallo', 'chorseride7679', 'ceelionking5454', 'crabuffallokjkj4', 'dgiraffeoiu9-0', 'chorseride767', 'ccatlive', 'dcatlive', 'ddogwish', 'emparkeetjump', 'emouse', 'eeelionking', 'erabuffallo', 'ffhorseride7679', 'fgeelionking5454', 'fhcrabuffallokjkj4', 'fkcgiraffeoiu9087', ]

big_animal = ['horse', 'lion', 'buffallo', 'giraffe']

count = 0
houses = Array.new(big_animal.length)

while count < ary.length do
    animals = 0
    if ary[count].include?(big_animal[animals])
        while animals < big_animal.length do
            if ary[count+animals].include?(big_animal[animals])
                houses[animals] = ary[count+animals]
                if animals == big_animal.length-1
                    puts houses
                end
            else
                houses = Array.new(big_animal.length)
            end
            animals = animals + 1
        end
    end
    count = count + 1
end
```

The above code gives me the following output:

```
chorseride7679
ceelionking5454
crabuffallokjkj4
dgiraffeoiu9-0
ffhorseride7679
fgeelionking5454
fhcrabuffallokjkj4
fkcgiraffeoiu9087
```

You can also [try it online here](https://tio.run/##jVJhb8IgEP3eX8G3zjiNS3TORLPsdxizQHu0WAqGlhl/fQe0WJRt7r5w3L337l2p0uTSdVhd0A7tU1xK1YBiOaTPKMX1CasKoD3q@uQKGW45@@qbuSzOrCltTu6BJACSEHijTxQmmlLMubTX7Npcv643rgLAmRQVE8VquVq60sipjtXR1fKCKUwpSKY3s0Uk5QqBoTzMA3NwvwXUUjcOBqMRd701TmnknBaxdVr@ZJ5WWWB/8WbtHpKEsOITC1Zj7h7GDbBwK@q@XTB/4KeGlkktWsNYJKX13pj0Qyl8mQs4P42acw6iaMtJkpxLxgH1tC0y/8HQQrlMkIke3zhJe2fUgvaOcJgzkXGdw3sgvR8Yh4nD2@hneKUtinz4YT7CIVOv989hPvr9rwCzQCwZkexgv/Au9jl7iRg2TrpthnlRH0R@UwPewC9eH73VX7LjM/lsikazHu1P/5f0p0WaTtd9Aw) and change the input array on that website to test different scenarios. I'd be happy to know if this is what you were searching for.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes i'm looking only if they are in the same order.
I also had an idea to store the loop with Hash.new actually, and you came with this Array.new solution. That's great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you wish to find four consecutive elements of `ary` that respectively include the strings given as elements of `big_animal`. If that is true all such consecutive elements from `ary` could be obtained as follows.

```
ary.each_cons(big_animal.size).select do |words|
  big_animal.each_index.all? { |i| words[i].include?(big_animal[i]) }
end
  #=> [["chorseride7679", "ceelionking5454", "crabuffallokjkj4", "dgiraffeoiu9-0"],
  #    ["ffhorseride7679", "fgeelionking5454", "fhcrabuffallokjkj4a",
  #     "fkcgiraffeoiu9087*s"]]
```

See [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing that you are looking for the first animal with the matching name , ending in a digit.

```
ary = ['ahorseride', 'amparkeetjump', 'acatlive', 'adogwish', 'bmparkeetjump',
 'bcatlive', 'bdogwish', 'bhorseride', 'brabuffallo', 'chorseride7679',
 'ceelionking5454', 'crabuffallokjkj4', 'dgiraffeoiu9-0', 'chorseride767',
 'ccatlive', 'dcatlive', 'ddogwish', 'emparkeetjump', 'emouse', 'eeelionking',
 'erabuffallo', 'ffhorseride7679', 'fgeelionking5454', 'fhcrabuffallokjkj4', 'fkcgiraffeoiu9087' ]

big_animal = ['horse', 'lion', 'buffallo', 'giraffe']

big_animal.each do |ba|
    rs = "#{ba}.*\\d$"
    rexp = Regexp.new rs 
    entry = ary.find { |i| i.match(rs) }
    puts "#{ba} in the house of #{entry}"
end

#horse in the house of chorseride7679
#lion in the house of ceelionking5454
#buffallo in the house of crabuffallokjkj4
#giraffe in the house of dgiraffeoiu9-0
```

Comment: It does work. Thank you so much!

I'm very noob to regex. I'll try to understand your code then. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/NxGr

By brazenly overriding String method. Better do not use this approach -))

```
class String
  def in_house? other
    (other.is_a? String) && (other.include? self)
  end

  def in_house_message_for other
    puts "#{self} in house of #{other}" if self.in_house? other
    return
  end
end
```

then

```
ary.each do |house|
  big_animal.each do |animal|
    animal.in_house_message_for(house)
  end
end
```

or that way to print in same order with `big_animal` array

```
big_animal.each do |animal|
  ary.each do |house|
    animal.in_house_message_for(house)
  end
end
```

the second one will print

```
horse in house of ahorseride
horse in house of bhorseride
horse in house of chorseride7679
horse in house of chorseride767
horse in house of ffhorseride7679
lion in house of ceelionking5454
lion in house of eeelionking
lion in house of fgeelionking5454
buffallo in house of brabuffallo
buffallo in house of crabuffallokjkj4
buffallo in house of erabuffallo
buffallo in house of fhcrabuffallokjkj4
giraffe in house of dgiraffeoiu9-0
giraffe in house of fkcgiraffeoiu9087
```

Comment: thank you so much @marmeladze.
It just still does printing animal not in the right order of array. The array supposed to print in the arrays contain the words of  big_animal in order the same as row as animals in big_animals

Comment: replace outer iteration with inner -)) let me update my answer